# Informatica integration service treats filter transformation as passive transformations?

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I had a question from my training.does the integration service treat the filter or update transformation as passive transformations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ramkumar - what do you mean by "if itegration service treats ..."?

Filter as well update strategy are both active. By definition any transformation that changes the number of rows passing thru it is active. Filter txfn does exactly this.

Update strategy is considered active because it changes row type. Although it doesn't by itself change the number of rows, it marks the rows for delete, insert or update producing the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Ramkumar - What do you mean by saying, "if the integration service treats..." Really, as you said, if filter is active, its active. I dont think there is a possibility yet that integration service can chose to treat a transformation as active or passive on a case to case basis...

Answer (score 0):

The filter is an active transformation, the update strategy passive.